# Jquery loop once or show data once in array of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using $.get() request to fetch data from Laravel controller and getting array of data in Javascript.

```
function getSpots1(){

var spots = $('#event-spots1');
    spots.empty();
    spots.html('<p><i class="uk-icon-refresh uk-icon-medium uk-icon-spin"></i></p>');
    var event_id = $("#event-event_id").val();
    var event_date = $("#event-date").val();
    var code = '';
    console.log(event_date);
    $.get("/1/users/spots/" + event_id + "/" + event_date + "/date", function(data) {
        spots.empty();
        console.log(data);

        code += '<label for="event_time" class="uk-form-label">Select Time</label><select class="uk-width-1-1" name="event_time" id="event-time">';
        $.each(data.spots, function(index, value) 
        {
            code += '<option value="' + value.event_time + '">' + value.event_time + '</option>';
        });

        code += '</select><p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-muted">The spot you\'re booking</p>';
        code += '</br><div class="uk-margin-bottom"><label for="event_time" class="uk-form-label">Price</label>';

        $.each(data.spots, function(index, value) 
        {
            code += '<input type="text" class="uk-width-1-1" value="' + value.price + '" disabled />';      
        });

        spots.append(code);
        getSpots2();
    });

}
```

I have $.each() jquery method to loop through array of Data. but for second $.each() method, I just need to loop once. I get value.price Multiple times depending on the loop length. For first $.each I need a loop because I have select input field.
Is there a another method instead of $.each to loop once through data variable? I am new and haven't really coded Jquery or Javascript before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could just get the first object in `data.spots` like for example `data.spots[0].event_time` and then you don't have to loop at all.

Less recommended, you could just put a `return false;` at the end of a loop like for example:

```
  $.each(data.spots, function(index, value) 
        {
            code += '<input type="text" class="uk-width-1-1" value="' + value.price + '" disabled />';   
            return false;
        });
```

which immediately stops the loop.

Comment: You are correct, why loop at all if you are only accessing one object?

Comment: Thank you, both solutions works. with loop and without it too :)